Is there a simple description in the dependent internal language of a topos of a partial morphism classifier as a slice over $\Omega$?
While writing up examples of partial morphism classifiers in various topoi, it struck me that in almost all cases, in the natural presentation you could see almost verbatim echoes of the corresponding examples of subobject classifier $\Omega$ at the start.  Furthermore, in converting a partial morphism $X \dashrightarrow Y$ to a morphism $X \to \tilde Y$, the first step tended to be a repetition of finding the characteristic morphism $X \to \Omega$ of the domain subobject of $X$.  (Just to give one of these examples briefly, in the case of sheaves of sets on a topological space, $\tilde{\mathscr{F}}$ is isomorphic to the sheaf mapping $U \mapsto \bigsqcup_{V \subseteq U} \mathscr{F}(V)$, where this is a disjoint union over sections of $\Omega(U) \simeq \{ V \subseteq U \mid V ~ \mathrm{open} \}$.)
Of course, we always have a canonical morphism $\tilde Y \to \Omega$ corresponding to the natural transformation $\operatorname{PartialHom}({-}, Y) \to \operatorname{Sub}$ sending a partial morphism to its domain of definition.  So, I was wondering whether there's a simple term in the dependently typed version of the internal language which would express that slice over $\Omega$.  A rough guess might be something along the lines of:
$$\lambda p : \Omega \, . \, \Sigma \{ x:1 \mid p \} \multimap Y$$
(where $\Sigma$ in the non-dependently-typed version is my notation for an operation which takes a term of type $PX$ with no free variables, and produces the corresponding subobject of $X$ -- of course, in this case, the term $\{ x : 1 \mid p \}$ does have $p$ as a free variable, so the interpretation here of $\Sigma \{ x : 1 \mid p \}$ might need to be something more like a functor taking a morphism $U \to \Omega$ and returning an object of $\mathcal{T} / U$).
However, I'm not nearly familiar enough with the dependently typed version of internal language to be able to tell whether that might be correct, or in fact whether it would even make sense.
(In what I'm currently writing up, the construction I'm using in the non-dependently-typed version of the internal language is $\tilde Y := \Sigma \{ S : PY \mid \forall y_1, y_2 : Y, (y_1 \in S \land y_2 \in S) \rightarrow y_1 = y_2 \}$.  That works fine for my purposes; it's just that the examples I presented as a follow-up to the general definition seemed to be making a strong case that there might be a more natural expression involving dependent types.)

Do you have a reference for the syntax of the internal language you speak of? My guess would be something like $p : \Omega \vdash p \to Y$, thinking of propositions as types, but I don't know how formal you want to make this.

Well, that's precisely part of the question, I don't have a reference for the precise syntax of the dependently-typed internal language, I've just vaguely heard that it exists and it's based on dependent types being interpreted as morphisms (or as objects in some slice of the topos).  That's why I'm pretty fuzzy on the details.

For that matter, I don't have a reference for the non-dependently-typed version either, it's just that in that case I've worked out my own version where the interpretation of a term of type $B$ with free variables of types $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ is a natural transformation $\prod_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Hom}({-}, A_i) \to \operatorname{Hom}({-}, B)$.

So if there's more standard notation for what I call $\Sigma S$, with $\mathsf{drop} : \Sigma S \hookrightarrow X$ and conditionally defined $\mathsf{lift}(\tau) : \Sigma { x:X \mid \varphi }$ for $\tau : X$ such that $\models \varphi[x:=\tau]$, feel free to correct me there.
